# Using reference to pointer as a sequence in C++11 range for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

The only difference between the following two snippets of code is the usage of reference. I understand why the first snippet does not compile and am seeking help in understanding why the second one compiles.

The first snippet:

```
int a[2][3] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
for (auto row : a)
  for (auto column : row)
    cout << column << endl;
```

The above code does not compile because the type of 'row' is pointer to int, which is not a sequence.

The second snippet:

```
int a[2][3] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
for (auto &row : a)
  for (auto column : row)
    cout << column << endl;
```

This code compiles. If I understand correctly how auto works, 'row' is a reference to pointer to int. But why can this reference be viewed as a sequence more than a regular pointer?

Comment: `row` is not a reference to pointer to int. It's a reference to an array of 3 ints - a `int (&)[3]`.

Comment: Thank you. But I am still confused. I understand that in C++ an array in an expression is always viewed as a pointer to the first element (that is why the first example did not compile). So how come 'row' is not converted to a pointer in the second example?

Comment: "an array in an expression is always viewed as a pointer to the first element" - no, an array *decays* to a pointer if used in a context that requires a pointer. The top answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) has a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Deduction of the type is done via template argument deduction.

```
template <typename U>
void foo(U&); // Equivalent to auto&

foo(row);
```

This will always deduce `U` to be the **exact type** of `row` (if it's an lvalue as in this case), which gives us the array type we desired.
Only for non-reference parameters is the array-to-pointer decay performed.

Answer (score 4):

Each element of the outer iteration is an array. In the first case `auto` takes the element by value so array to pointer decay happens and you can't then loop over a single pointer.

In the second case you get a reference to the array, which you can of course iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

`std::begin` and `std::end` don't have overloads for pointer types. Ranged-based for loop are defined to use these functions. If you want to prevent the array-to-pointer conversion from happening, you can bind a reference to the array.

§8.5.3

> `5` A reference to type "*cv1* `T1`" is initialized by an expression
>   of type "*cv2* `T2`" as follows:
>
> > — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer
> >     expression
> >
> > > — is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and "*cv1* `T1`" is
> > >       reference-compatible with "*cv2* `T2`," or
> > >
> > > — has a class type (i.e., `T2` is a class type), where `T1` is not
> > >       reference-related to `T2`, and can be implicitly converted to an
> > >       lvalue of type "*cv3* `T3`," where "*cv1* `T1`" is
> > >       reference-compatible with "*cv3* `T3`"<sup>106</sup> (this conversion
> > >       is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion functions
> > >       (13.3.1.6) and choosing the best one through overload resolution
> > >       (13.3)),
> >
> > then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in
> >     the first case and to the lvalue result of the conversion in the
> >     second case (or, in either case, to the appropriate base class
> >     subobject of the object). [ *Note:* The usual lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1),
> >     array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard
> >     conversions are not needed, and therefore are suppressed, when such
> >     direct bindings to lvalues are done. — *end note* ]

Since the second bullet point doesn't apply, then the reference binds *directly* to the array and no conversion happens.